# jQuery UI buttons - keep active state, ignore hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, hover

As mentioned in another question earlier, I have a system that displays content and highlights a button based on the hash tag. This is working fine for the most part, but **if you hover the button, it then loses it's active state.**

Here's a **[working example][1]** of the problem.

I've tried `.hover(function() {return false;});` but unfortunately this didn't work (though I guess I didn't expect it to...!). I've also tried disabling the button (then re-enabling it when you click another one) which was perfect in Firefox, but the text was greyed out in IE7.

Would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you :)

Comment: You just linked to `http://localhost`. That's almonst as smart as `[img]file:///C:/Users/..../me.jpg[/img]` in some forums :p

Comment: replace localhost with your ip address or post a demo to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oh my, I cannot believe I did that! Updated the link, that's for pointing that out guys :-)

Comment: Making a jsfiddle makes it a lot easier for us to locate the problem than scoring through a live site.

Comment: I'm unable to see the issue and code because it wasn't a jsfiddle....  So much for this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with your button are submitting the #, it doesn't make the link go to another page but it generates some unwanted scrolling. You should avoid that like this.

```
$('#showScarringReports').click(function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); });
```

After if you want the active state to stay you can disable the event handler which make it switch from active back to what it was. So again with first one as example.

```
$('#showScarringReports').unbind('mouseout keyup mouseup hover');
```

Once active it will stay active, to remove the active state then just remove the class ui-state-hover from the button.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect - thank you so so much! Not only have you solved the problem, you've also fixed another issue too - really appreciate it, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The other solution did not work for me so I had to use this one:

```
$('#my-button')
    .button({disabled:true})
    .removeClass('ui-state-disabled')
    .addClass('ui-state-active') //permanently pressed
    .addClass('ui-state-hover')  //or permanently highlighted
;
```